# What does neural computation mean ?

Tags: neural-networks

Does it mean given an input to the neural network an output is produced ? In the recently launched iPhone X there is a neural engine that can perform 600 billion operations in a sec. Are those operations like outputs at the nodes of a neural network ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like "neural computation" is being used here as a buzzword referring to the use of artificial neural nets. I'm not aware of any common technical use of this term in machine learning. It is, however, commonly used in neuroscience to refer to the operation of the brain or biological neural networks, at a computational/algorithmic level of description (rather than a biological/mechanistic one). This is very different from artificial neural nets, which bear only a loose resemblance to their biological counterparts. Describing an iPhone in terms of "neural computation" sounds rather silly and out of place. To interpret the $600 \times 10^9$ ops/s spec, more information would needed about what exactly those operations are.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Perhaps, I should have focussed on either asking about neural computation or the neural engine that Apple launched. Thanks

Comment: @GSH Hmm, I hope that wasn't worded too ambiguously. Just to be clear, I wasn't trying to say that *you* sound silly (it's a perfectly reasonable question)...rather, it's funny imagining the term being used in a marketing context to sell iphones